# Adding multiple keys to the dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I create dictionary in python:`d = dict.fromkeys(['one', 'two', 'three'], 1)`

But I don't know, how can I add the multiple keys to this dictionary like 
['one2', 'two2', 'three2'] -> 2

So, result dictionary should be:

['one', 'two', 'three'] -> 1
['one2', 'two2', 'three2'] -> 2

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, could you format the output like - `{'one': 1, 'two': 1, 'three': 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is updating with the result of another `dict.fromkeys` dictionary:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(['one', 'two', 'three'], 1)
d.update(dict.fromkeys( ['one2', 'two2', 'three2'] , 2))
```

result:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 1, 'two2': 2, 'three2': 2, 'three': 1, 'one2': 2}
```

Can be tedious if you have more data to update like this. In that case, make a list of tuples with keys/value and "flatten" it using dict comprehension:

```
kv = [(['one', 'two', 'three'], 1),(['one2', 'two2', 'three2'] , 2)]

d = {k:v for kl,v in kv for k in kl}
```